# Sharing GPU between host and guest

Tags: nvidia, kvm, qemu, gpu, gpu-passthrough

Is there a way to make both host and guest use a singular GPU without any paid software (vGPU)?

Bonus points if it:

- Dynamically allocates GPU resources
- Works for AMD and Intel GPUS

I have an nVidia GPU, a Linux host and a Windows guest.

Perhaps a Linux alternative to https://github.com/jamesstringerparsec/Easy-GPU-PV

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Peregrino69 passthrough is an exclusive thing, not a shared thing.

Comment: Thx @MarcusMüller :-) I was searching that as OP tagged gpu-passthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Both spice, used by Qemu/KVM, as well as virtualbox, offer accelerated 3D from the guest, which essentially means they translate openGL calls.

That *is* sharing the host GPU with the VM, through the well-standardized openGL API.

If you want to, however, do something like using GPGPU (e.g CUDA, openCL):

No, that is currently not possible. If you want to virtualize *parts* of your GPU, you will need a datacenter GPU from nvidia, and the datacenter license for CUDA. I'm not aware of any of that being available with other vendors.